# How do I use the field type of a record in other places in elm

Tags: typescript, types, elm

Consider this:

```
type alias Foo = 
    { id : String
    , name : String
    }

type alias Bar = 
    { id : Foo.id
    , name : String
    }
```

This does not work in elm to my knowledge. (By this I mean the use of "Foo.id").

I could set the id field in Bar as String but I want it to use the id type of another record. So that when/if I need to refactor it later I can do it in only one place.
This is the error message I see when I try to do this *

> The type expected 0 arguments, but got 1 instead

Extra Context: I am fairly new to Elm language and functional programming in general. I have a fair bit of Typescript experience. So I am used to creating well defined types. Not sure if that's how its done in Elm. So I'm here to learn and discover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are inclined to deduplicate the type for `id` field, you may consider extracting it into its own type:

```
type alias Id = String

type alias Foo = 
    { id : Id
    , name : String
    }

type alias Bar = 
    { id : Id
    , name : String
    }
```

Comment: Yes that has been my current workaround, but is there no direct solution? Because it becomes too much of boilerplate to do that with every time I want to get the field type of a record.

Comment: You have to clarify what you mean by "boilerplate" because it is not obvious in this context. Maybe provide an example of the pattern you are trying to port to Elm from another language and someone might give you the Elm equivalent.

Comment: @pdamoc
By "boilerplate" I mean "needing to do more to do the same* thing".
I will try to come up with a good example for my use case but in the meanwhile, can you help me understand why this is not a thing? I dont think doing "Foo.id" to get the type is against functional programming. Is it because of some thing else?

Comment: @oreychandan , it is not a thing because it was not implemented. Implementing features like these require an extreme amount of time in design and analysis due to the interaction with the rest of the features. For example `foo.id` is syntax sugar for `.id foo` where `.id` is `.id : { r | id : a } -> a` and is generated automatically by the compiler. by the same logic `Foo.id` would be `.id Foo` and that would be a type level function. There are none of that in Elm. Other languages have such advanced concepts but Elm strives to be simple.

Comment: @oreychandan I apologize if my answer sounded condescending. It was not my intention. This is not the first time I'm told this. I don't know why I sound like that.  In any case... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It will wrap strings in an `Id` AND add a type that helps you enforce proper usage:

```elm
    type UserId = UserId -- we have a type called "UserId" who's only value is "UserId"
    
    
    type ProjectId = ProjectId -- ...
    
    
    type Id a = Id String -- an Id has a specific type "a" and is always a wrapper for a string
    
    
    userId : String -> Id UserId
    user = Id -- Id is always a constructor, but the type signature forces Elm to treat this as a "Id UserId". Only code that expects an "Id UserId" can accept this
    
    
    projectId : String -> Id ProjectId
    project = Id


    -- any Id can be turned back into a string
    toString : Id a -> String
    toString (Id a) = a
```

Comment: ooh, this sounds interesting. i'll have to experiment with this and come back